# Retrieving ActionLink parameter from URL

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I have the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Customer Number", "Search", new { Search = ViewBag.Search, q = ViewBag.q, sortOrder = ViewBag.CustomerNoSortParm, })
```

With both viewbag properties coming from the URL:

```
http://localhost:51488/Home/Search?Search=Postcode&q=test&sortOrder=CustomerNo
```

However the URL produced is:

```
http://localhost:51488/Home/Search?sortOrder=CustomerNo
```

with it not picking up either of the ViewBag values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewBag doesn't come from the URL. It comes from the controller action. If you want to fetch query string parameters or parameters that were part of a POST request you could use the `Request`:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Customer Number", 
    "Search", 
    new { 
        Search = Request["Search"], 
        q = Request["q"], 
        sortOrder = Request["CustomerNoSortParm"] 
    }
)
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can retrieve the "Customer Number" label directly from the model. Similar to @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerNumber)?

Comment: Can't you use `@Model.CustomerNumber`?

Answer (score 0):

ViewBag let you share data from the controller to the View.

If you want to use data from the URL to create your link, you will need to use the FormCollection of your controller's action (if you build the link inside the controller) or to use directly the HttpContext (which is accessible from the View)

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Search"]
```